# tool to share text file and notify collaborators of file changes?

Tags: sync, dropbox, file-sharing, text-editors, shared-folders

I would like a tool that will allow me to share a text file with a colleague, and if the file changes, will email them with a list of any additions or deletions.

I believe Dropbox can notify you (using RSS) if files are added or deleted from a shared folder, but I would like a tool that will email them a diff, a list of lines that have changed.

Ideally this tool would:

- allow me to work with a text file on my local hard drive (rather than on the web)
- allow them to edit the file and autosync to my local file, so that the next time I open the text file, their changes will be apparent

And again:

- if I update the file, my colleague automatically receives an email with a list of my changes and additions
- if they update the file, I automatically receive an email with a list of therir changes and additions

Does such a tool exist? Or is there a way to do this with Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a webserver, one option would be [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/).

For a client based editing, there's [Abiword](http://abisource.com/) which uses some centralized location to store the document.

Both above can be used to modify files at the same time, and see others changes in realtime.

At work we've used Microsoft Sharepoint, but that's not free or very nice to use (my opinion).